# 'Router' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

**Error Message**

```
'Router' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.  TS2786

 import App from './App';
    5 | 
  > 6 | ReactDOM.render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**index.tsx code**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Router.tsx code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

export default function Routes() {
  <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </>;
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

What is this error ?

Error in index.tsx `<Router />`

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: you are not returning anything from your component.

Comment: If you only have one route why are you using `react-router` at all? Just have `App` be your source component.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to comment but I dont have enough reputation,
But as your error code is saying you are not return anything in the `Router.tsx`.
Try add the return statement in the Router function like so

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I get the same error but now inside the empty element.

Answer (score 6):

1. Returning an array of JSX elements instead of a single element. To solve the error, we have to wrap the array using a React fragment or a div element.
2. Returning any value other than a JSX element or null from a component.
3. Having outdated versions of React typings.

```bash
# ️ with NPM
npm install --save-dev @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
    
# ️ if you also want to update react and react-dom
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
    
# ------------------------------
    
# ️ with YARN
yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev
    
# ️ if you also want to update react and react-dom
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Router.tsx file to

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

export default function Routes() {
    return (
      <>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    )
}
```